# ScrollView com Imagens e LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile gostaria de deixar a aplicação com esse visual uma aplicação horizontal com uma uma imagem lado a lado e com um ScrollView

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu ja tentei tirar o ScrollView, mas a tela do celular corta as duas ultimas imagens abaixo do  filme O Regresso e Matar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando adiciono o  ScrollView para poder rolar a barra de rolagem para baixo e visualizar os filmes abaixo do O Regresso e Matar ele apresenta o seguinte erro ,ScrollView can only one direct child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.tulio.exercicio5.MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/aliados" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/chamado3" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/regresso" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/john_wick" />

</LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/residentevil6" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/xxxreativado" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu caso você tem 2 filhos para o scrollview, e o mesmo só aceita uma view filho para sua hierarquia..
Darei um exemplo de forma correta e forma incorrecta.

**CORRETA**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.example.tulio.exercicio5.MainActivity">
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            <LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Observe que temos 3 lineares layout dentro do scrollview, mas apenas um é filho direto do mesmo.

**INCORRETA**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.tulio.exercicio5.MainActivity">
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Se parar para analisar, verá que o scrollview dessa vez possui 2 LinearLayout filhos, com isto causará o erro :

> a scroll view can only have one child

Answer (score 0):

O ScrollView só aceita uma View/Layout dentro dele.

Não posso ter a certeza mas parece-me que, nesse seu caso, ele deviria ser o primeiro elemento:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.tulio.exercicio5.MainActivity">
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    ...
    ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Eventualmemte terá de ajustar os valores de `android:layout_width` e `android:layout_height` tanto do ScrollView como do primeiro LinearLayout.